# Angular ui-grid - Moving filter section in column menu

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I've started using ui-grid for past few weeks. The column filter is really good, but I want to make the look and feel much better. Is there any way to move the filter option inside the column menu?

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name', enableColumnMenu: false,
        filters: [
          {
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.STARTS_WITH,
            placeholder: 'Starts with'
          },
          {
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.CONTAINS,
            placeholder: 'contains'
          }
        ]
      },
      { field: 'gender', enableHiding: false, suppressRemoveSort: true, sort: { direction: uiGridConstants.ASC } },
      {
        field: 'company',
        menuItems: [
          {
            title: 'Outer Scope Alert',
            icon: 'ui-grid-icon-info-circled',
            action: function($event) {
              this.context.blargh();
            },
            context: $scope
          },
          {
            title: 'Grid ID',
            action: function() {
              alert('Grid ID: ' + this.grid.id);
            }
          },
          {
            title: 'Better to have filter options here!',
            action: function() {
              alert(this.context.col.displayName);
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

[Fiddle 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/eJ3bC3mRhia3Mf8HgiSz?p=preview)

Also, I was trying to position the filter section so that I can make it available in a dropdown on user demand. But this breaks the grid header when we have horizontal scroll bar.

```
.ui-grid-top-panel, .ui-grid-header-viewport{ overflow: visible;}
.listview-header.ui-grid-header-cell { overflow: visible; }
.listview-header.ui-grid-header-cell div[ui-grid-filter]{ position:absolute; right:0; width:125px; background-color:#eee; border:1px solid #ddd; z-index:1; }
```

[Fiddle 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/kuVEBokM1JGkeo3fdTTB?p=preview)

Does anyone have a good idea to improve the look and feel of the filter section?

Answer (score 1):

I have created an issue with the ui-grid team, they have added this feature in their roadmap. Eagerly waiting for it!

Thanks team! [GitHub Issue 3989](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/3989)